# How to view services with no description only?

Tags: services, powershell-core

I have this piece of code

`Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | Format-List Name, Description`

which shows me all the services and their descriptions, but when I added

`| Where-Object {$_.Description -eq ""}`

to show me which services have no descriptions, nothing showed up. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Entire code is:
`Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | Format-List Name, Description | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can swap the last 2 commands and test that the description's length is equal to 0 (empty). The list will be shown.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.Description.length -eq 0} | Format-List Name, Description
```